# What MIDI hardware do iOS 4.2 compatible devices support?

Tags: ios, camera

(Apologies ahead of time if this question belongs in the audio production stack exchange. Since this question directly involves iOS, it seemed more appropriate here.)

A while back I ran across a webpage which claimed to have a maintained list of which midi devices were tested on iOS devices for compatibility. Does anyone know where I could find this list or one like it?

(For those interested, it was discovered during the betas for 4.2 that, by using the camera connection kit, one could connect certain midi devices to the iPad and transfer midi data back and forth.)

Thank you,
-b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just came upon the site I was looking for in relation to this question. I'm posting it in case others inquire.

http://iosmidi.com/

-b

Comment: Direct link to (outdated) list: http://iosmidi.com/devices/

Answer (score 1):

Every USB device that is compliant to the USB Midi class specification which does not draw significant power from the USB port works as a midi device using the camera connection kit.

Most devices that do draw from USB power can be run using a powered hub connected to the camera connection kit when the powered hub is plugged into an electrical outlet.

Some USB midi devices do not completely follow the USB Midi class, and they may not work, or will only work erratically, but this is rare.